# Production logistics for recycling on Mythbusters

Tags: production, mythbusters

The cast and crew of Mythbusters make an amazing number of gadgets, test platforms, small scale buildings, etc. for each and every episode.  They take great pride in destroying their creations whenever possible.  While this is fun to watch, it seems like it creates a tremendous amount of waste.

Is there any reliable information out there (from the producers or otherwise) about what the show does with all of the material?  Is it recycled?

Comment: I think this goes beyond simple trivia, but I don't know which aspects of production are fair game.  Let me know if this seems reasonable.

Comment: I found this humorous, but not very useful answer on Yahoo Answers http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120212173205AAQAXj4

Comment: Look at Buster ... he's been recycled *many* times ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a comprehensive answer by any means, but in this excerpt

at around 2:20 Jamie Hyneman states that the ramp they are building is made of roof trusses and that

> We're also going to put them together with screws so we can recycle the lumber.